# How to get url of Active Storage image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

I want to get list of records with attached images as a links or files by api.

I have a simple model:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :image
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

And next action:

```
  def index
    @categories = Category.all.with_attached_image

    render json: @categories.to_json(include: { image_attachment: { include: :blob } })
  end
```

That's the only way I can get image object.

And I see next results:

```
{"id":4,"name":"Cat1","description":""},
{"id":1,"name":"Cat2","description":"","image_attachment":
  {"id":8,"name":"image","record_type":"Category","record_id":1,"blob_id":8,"created_at":"2018-06-09T13:45:40.512Z","blob":
  {"id":8,"key":"3upLhH4vGxZEhhf3TaAjDiCW","filename":"Screen Shot 2018-06-09 at 20.43.24.png","content_type":"image/png","metadata":
  {"identified":true,"width":424,"height":361,"analyzed":true},"byte_size":337347,"checksum":"Y58zbYUVOlZRadx81wxOJA==","created_at":"2018-06-09T13:45:40.482Z"}}},
...
```

I can see filename here. But files lives in different folders and it doesn't seems for me like a convenient way to get and link to the file.

I couldn't find any information about this.

**Updated**

Accordin to iGian solution my code become:

```
  def index
    @categories = Category.all.with_attached_image

    render json: @categories.map { |category|
      category.as_json.merge({ image: url_for(category.image) })
    }
  end
```

Comment: I have a model User with avatar as attachment and I can get the url in my views with `<%= image_tag url_for(user.avatar) %>`, maybe you can use just `url_for(user.avatar)`.

Comment: Yes, that works, thank you!

Comment: Good, glad to help!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

For my `User` which `has_one_attached :avatar` I can get the url in my views with `<%= image_tag url_for(user.avatar) %>`.
So, in controller I would use just `url_for(user.avatar)`

For `Category` which `has_one_attached :image`:

```
url_for(category.image)
```

Comment: how can we get Image complete data from Image_url `vice-versa`

Comment: If you need the full path you can use `polymorphic_url(category.image)`, which includes `https://...` not just the path.

Comment: Try `main_app.url_for(category.image)`

Comment: I just want to add that if you're not accessing this from a view, you can do this:
`Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.url_for(category.image)`

Answer (score 17):

Also try `@object.image.service_url`. This will give you the url where the image is saved. I.E. url to amazon s3 storage.

Comment: This works with Rails 6.1 below, but stopped working on Rails 7. It is now renamed from `service_url` to just `url`.

Comment: This works as of Jun 2022 +1

Comment: use `url` with Rails 7. Tested it on Oct 2023

Answer (score 4):

Please follow this for fetching images( in case if you are using **has_many_attached**)

```
Model.images.map{|img| ({ image: url_for(img) })}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I can't convert from single to multiple attachments using only the the line in your answer. I get either just the 'images' array in the response, or an error, meaning I'm doing something wrong. Could you possibly put this answer into the context of the original poster's 'index' method block?

Comment: I got this to work, would it be the correct way, syntactically?

`render json: @works.map { |work|
      work.as_json.merge({ images: work.images.map{|img| ({ image: url_for(img) })} })
    }
`

Answer (score 4):

This works for me with multiple images

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  attributes :id, :content , :images

  def images
    images = object.images.map do |image|
      rails_blob_path(image , only_path: true) if object.images.attached?
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work with `rails_blob_url(@object.image)`. Notice I am calling **_url** not **_path** with the helper.

Answer (score 1):

If you want get this url in front end, try this :

```
<%= url_for(category.image) %>
```

and for displaying image :

```
<%= image_tag url_for(category.image) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I use active storage with AWS S3 bucket and attach image urls with domain to JSON response:

**activerecord**

```
class Imageable < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :images

  def image_urls
    images.map(&:service_url)
  end

  def attributes
    super.merge({
                  image_urls: image_urls
                })
  end
end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_active_storage_current_host
  
  def set_active_storage_current_host
    ActiveStorage::Current.host = request.base_url
  end
end
```

**imageables_controller.rb**

```
class ImageablesController < ApplicationController
  include ImageablesHelper
  def update
    imageable = find_or_create
    imageable.update imageables_params
    imageable.images.purge
    imageable.images.attach imageable_params[:images]
    imageable.save!
    render json: imageable
  end
end
```

**imageables_helper.rb**

```
module ImageablesHelper
  def imageables_params
    params.require(:imageable).permit(:other_attributes, images: [])
  end
end
```